# Function returning before the result from a promise?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, es6-promise

```
getShowPopup(fileName,zoneId) {
        return this.getDataFromServer(fileName,zoneId).then((response) => { 
            return response;
        });
}

const showPopup = this.Service.getShowPopup(fileName,this.id);
```

showPopup is assigned with an **undefined** value. On debugging, the getShowPopup method is returning value before the promise is executed. How can I make this synchronous so that it waits for the response and then return the correct result.

Comment: It looks like `getShowPopup` returns a promise. Are you sure `showPopup` is `undefined`? Btw, there is no point in doing `.then(response => {return respone;}`, you can just remove that part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: "asynchronous so that it waits for the response" — That's the opposite of what asynchronous means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think better approach is to make it like this:

```
// it should return Promise
function getShowPopup(fileName,zoneId) {
        return this.getDataFromServer(fileName,zoneId);
}

// and then when you want to get value from this api call
const showPopup = this.Service.getShowPopup(fileName,this.id)
    .then(response => response)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

now showPopup const should have value.
Other approach is to make function async

```
async function getShowPopup(fileName,zoneId) {
        return this.getDataFromServer(fileName,zoneId);
}
```

and then you will only have to use key word await

```
// but if api call returns error, it will not be caught so you should put this call in try catch block
const showPopup = await this.Service.getShowPopup(fileName, this.id);
```

Comment: I just appended await and not its waiting for the response before executing further.   <br/>      `const showPopup = await this.Service.getShowPopup(fileName, this.id);`

Comment: `getDataFromServer(param1, param2)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let subs: Subscription = this.read.subscribe((res) => {
            subs.unsubscribe();
            resolve(true);
        },
            (err) => {
                subs.unsubscribe();
                resolve(false);
            })
    })
}`

Comment: You don't have to make the the function `async` to be able to use `await`. `await` works with *promises*. `getShowPopup` already returns a promise in the first example (because `this.getDataFromServer` does).

Comment: @jitenderd can you post whole piece of code (I think it is a class) where getDataFromServer function is located? maybe edit your question, it will be easier to read